# input parameter value is null; not able to retry, throws exception from underlying ODA driver. SQL error #1:Unsupported feature

Tags: oracle, parameters, null, prepared-statement, birt

I have a BIRT report (3.7) that is not rendering the parameter drop down. The mystery is that it renders in our local and test environment using mysql and oracle db but not in our client's environment. That is why I am having hard time replicating and solving the issue. The dropdown is always blank, we checked the log error and here is it is:

Any suggestion on how I can solve this? This remained unsolved for more a week now. thanks

```
    Apr 15, 2014 1:04:32 PM org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement retrySetNullParamValue
SEVERE: Input parameter value is null; not able to retry, throws exception from underlying ODA driver.
Apr 15, 2014 1:04:32 PM org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement retrySetNullParamValue
SEVERE: Cannot set input parameter.
org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot set a null value to parameter 1.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot set preparedStatement null value.
SQL error #1:Unsupported feature
;
    java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.newException(ExceptionHandler.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.doSetNull(PreparedStatement.java:4651)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.setNull(PreparedStatement.java:4173)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.setParameterValue(PreparedStatement.java:3113)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.setParameterValue(PreparedStatement.java:3070)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.setInputParameterBinding(DataSourceQuery.java:1104)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.addParameterDefns(DataSourceQuery.java:568)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.prepare(DataSourceQuery.java:286)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.prepareOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.executeQuery(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:640)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.getResultSetForParameter(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:1369)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.getChoicesFromParameterQuery(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:1341)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.doGetSelectionList(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:493)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.getSelectionList(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:445)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.getSelectionListForCascadingGroup(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:724)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.getSelectionListForCascadingGroup(BirtViewerReportService.java:777)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.parameter.ComboBoxParameterFragment.getParameterSelectionListForCascadingGroup(ComboBoxParameterFragment.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.parameter.ComboBoxParameterFragment.prepareParameterBean(ComboBoxParameterFragment.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.parameter.ScalarParameterFragment.doService(ScalarParameterFragment.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:76)
        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.parameter.ParameterGroupFragment_jsp._jspService(ParameterGroupFragment_jsp.java:141)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
        at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.include(RequestWrapper.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.dialog.ParameterDialogFragment_jsp._jspService(ParameterDialogFragment_jsp.java:109)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
        at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.include(RequestWrapper.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.callBack(AbstractBaseFragment.java:106)
        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.dialog.DialogContainerFragment_jsp._jspService(DialogContainerFragment_jsp.java:135)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
        at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.include(RequestWrapper.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.callBack(AbstractBaseFragment.java:106)
        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.layout.SidebarFragment_jsp._jspService(SidebarFragment_jsp.java:72)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
        at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.include(RequestWrapper.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.callBack(AbstractBaseFragment.java:106)
        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.layout.ReportFragment_jsp._jspService(ReportFragment_jsp.java:72)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
        at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.include(RequestWrapper.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.callBack(AbstractBaseFragment.java:106)
        at org.apache.jsp.webcontent.birt.pages.layout.FramesetFragment_jsp._jspService(FramesetFragment_jsp.java:265)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
        at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.include(RequestWrapper.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.FramesetFragment.service(FramesetFragment.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet.__doGet(ViewerServlet.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doGet(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:160)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.irondata.icm.server.servlet.filters.IcmSessionFilter.doFilter(IcmSessionFilter.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:163)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The datasource is from xml which generates this tag:

```
<report name=" Reports">
<provider idNo="7" providerName="Test 1"/>
<provider idNo="1" providerName="Test 2"/>
<provider idNo="2" providerName="Test 3"/>
</report>
```

Comment: I am assuming this is a dynamic list parameter.  If so; when you create a report that mimicks the dynamic list is the client able to display the report?  If not a dynamic list; what kind of parameter is it?

Comment: this is a dynamic paramter from a xml datasource. This one is being used for a report as regular param and cascading in the other. Both are not displaying. Yes, the report is generated when we set a default data like (-1) as ALL. tnx

Comment: we were able to solve our problem. The prob was not in our code nor in anything. But instead it was in the url path in app config in the db for the service. Turns out the http://www.localhost/8081 in their environment is not configured that way. it was http://www.localhost/8035. The error means the dataset is not filled with anything coz the url is wrong in the first place.